# How to pass database data to view input in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im trying to make edit button for checkboxes with inputs checkboxes

Screenshot: http://gyazo.com/381e44b71e7b62d257bff0a0361b5d61

i have already done with insert function and its work.

in table i have database like

```
 id  property_id  property_type_id     alt_txt  
------  -----------  ----------------  ------------
     1            1                 1        25
     2            2                 1        30
     4            7                 1        50
    49            6                 1        60
```

property_type_id related with checkboxes and alt_txt with inputs

how to pass this data to them when click edit

I have try to make model function like

```
function get_by_id($id){
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            return $this->db->get($this->_table_name);
    }
```

in controller i call it like

```
 $this->data['type'] = $this->type_m->get_by_id($id);
```

and in var_dump i recive

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#232 (8) {
  ["conn_id"]=>
  resource(45) of type (mysql link)
  ["result_id"]=>
  resource(87) of type (mysql result)
  ["result_array"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["result_object"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["custom_result_object"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["current_row"]=>
  int(0)
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["row_data"]=>
  NULL
}
```

please help me to make this edit function.

**EDIT:**

Here is part from my view code:

```
    <fieldset>
                    <!--        Form Name -->                
                    <legend>Choose property type</legend>

<!--                 Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
                    <?php echo form_checkbox('data[1][property_type_id]', '22', set_value('data[1][property_type_id]', $type->property_type_id), 'id="checkboxes-0"')?>
                      PentHause
                    </label>
                      <br>
<!--                 Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                <?php  echo form_input('data[1][alt_txt]', set_value('data[1][alt_txt]',$type->alt_txt), 'class="form-control" id="cena" placeholder="Enter Price"')?>

                  </div>
                </div>

                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
                <?php echo form_checkbox('data[2][property_type_id]', '21', set_value('data[2][property_type_id]', $type->property_type_id), 'id="checkboxes-1"')?>
                      Garage
                    </label>
                <br>
<!--                                         Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                <?php echo form_input('data[2][alt_txt]', set_value('data[2][alt_txt]', $type->alt_txt), 'class="form-control" id="cena" placeholder="Enter Price"')?>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it and ill share for these who have same situation:

Model Function:

```
    public function get_by_id($id){
        $item = $this->db->get_where($this->_table_name,array("property_id"=>$id));
        return $item->result_array();
}
```

In controller i call like

```
            $type_array = $this->type_m->get_by_id($id);

  foreach($type_array as $estate_obj){
        $type = array();
        $type['id'] = $estate_obj['id'];
        $type['property_id'] = $estate_obj['property_id'];
        $type['property_type_id'] = $estate_obj['property_type_id'];
        $type['alt_txt'] = $estate_obj['alt_txt']; 
        //var_dump($type);
        $this->data['type'][$type['property_type_id']] = $type;
  }
```

And this is how i made it in view:

```
       <fieldset>
                    <!--        Form Name -->                
                    <legend>Изберете типове за имота</legend>

<!--                 Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
                    <?php echo form_checkbox('data[1][property_type_id]', '22', set_value('data[1][property_type_id]',$type[22]['property_type_id']), 'id="checkboxes-0"')?>
                      Пентхаус
                    </label>
                      <br>
            <!--    Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <?php echo form_input('data[1][alt_txt]', set_value('data[1][alt_txt]', isset($type[22]['alt_txt'])?$type[22]['alt_txt']:''), 'class="form-control" id="cena" placeholder="Въведи цена"')?>
                  </div>
                </div>

                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
                <?php echo form_checkbox('data[2][property_type_id]', '21', set_value('data[2][property_type_id]', $type[21]['property_type_id']), 'id="checkboxes-1"')?>
                      Гараж/Паркомясто
                    </label>
                <br>
            <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <?php echo form_input('data[2][alt_txt]', set_value('data[1][alt_txt]', isset($type[21]['alt_txt'])?$type[21]['alt_txt']:''), 'class="form-control" id="cena" placeholder="Въведи цена"')?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-2">
                    <?php echo form_checkbox('data[3][property_type_id]', '20', set_value('data[3][property_type_id]',$type[20]['property_type_id']), 'id="checkboxes-2"')?>
                     Бизнес
                    </label>
                    <br>
                         <!--Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <?php echo form_input('data[3][alt_txt]', set_value('data[3][alt_txt]', isset($type[20]['alt_txt'])?$type[20]['alt_txt']:''), 'class="form-control" id="cena" placeholder="Въведи цена"')?>

                 </div>
                </div>
```

And problem got sloved! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier if you are just wanting 1 row to use the get_where() method in your model:

```
$item = $this->db->get_where($this->_table_name,array("id"=>$id),1,0);

return ($item->num_rows() == 1) ? $item->row() : false;
```

This way you are selecting 1 row using the limit and offset parameters of get_where(), checking the result has a single row and returning that row object, otherwise false to fail the call.

Comment: Thank you now i get passed them to inputs but they passed same value to all inputs check edited question and here whats happing http://gyazo.com/8a2971a6b1b0cdd4e70cbd1fc5db6d61 
in case we have diffirend values for second checkbox 
http://gyazo.com/ab5461e0d0d96ba6e3229d05ed9f270b